# Get multiple matches in string between two strings - small issue in function that I use?

Tags: php

I have this input:

```
somerandomcharacters[code]object1[/code]somerandomcharacters[code]object2[/code]somerandomcharacters[code]object3[/code]somerandomcharacters
```

And I need to get this output:

```
array("object1", "object2", "object3");
```

I use this function:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
$split_string       = explode($end,$string);
foreach($split_string as $data) {
$str_pos       = strpos($data,$start);
$last_pos      = strlen($data);
$capture_len   = $last_pos - $str_pos;
$return[]      = substr($data,$str_pos+1,$capture_len);
}
return $return;
}
```

So:

```
    $input = "somerandomcharacters[code]object1[/code]somerandomcharacters[code]object2[/code]somerandomcharacters[code]object3[/code]somerandomcharacters";
    $start = "[code]";
    $end = "[/code]";
    $outputs = get_string_between($input, $start, $end);

    foreach($outputs as $output)
    echo "$output </br>";
```

But foreach return this:

```
code]object1 
code]object2 
code]object3 
omerandomcharacters
```

Can you please help me where is the problem in the function? It looks like that work opposite than I need, isn't it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = "somerandomcharacters[code]object1[/code]somerandomcharacters[code]object2[/code]somerandomcharacters[code]object3[/code]somerandomcharacters";

preg_match_all('%\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]%i', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

---

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => object1
    [1] => object2
    [2] => object3
)
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]

Options: Case insensitive

Match the character “[” literally «\[»
Match the character string “code” literally (case insensitive) «code»
Match the character “]” literally «\]»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “[” literally «\[»
Match the character string “/code” literally (case insensitive) «/code»
Match the character “]” literally «\]»
```

---

DEMO: http://ideone.com/wVvssx